# How to solve this responsive grid math

Tags: css, math, sass, grid-layout

I need some help solving this mathematical grid layout problem. Maybe I'm just overthinking this, but I can't seem to find a way to code this grid so it works exactly as in the pictures shown below.

Original:

[image]

Wanted:

[image]

The difference between the first one and the second one is basically a responsive breakpoint. We go from 3 columns layout to a 2 columns one. For the sake of accessibility, this has to be a ul with li inside.

I had a working solution when using different html elements like div and article which when like that :

```
@for $i from 1 through 30 {
    div:nth-of-type(#{$i * 2 - 1}), article:nth-of-type(#{$i * 2}) {
        order:#{$i * 2 - 1};
        @include flex(0 0 50%);
    }

    article:nth-of-type(#{$i * 2 - 1}), section:nth-of-type(#{$i * 2}) {
        order:#{$i * 2};
    }
}
```

Just to be more clear, here is the expected behavior of every block in the grid

```
Original order --> New order
1     -->     1
2     -->     2
3     -->     5
4     -->     3
5     -->     4
6     -->     7
7     -->     6
8     -->     9
9     -->     10
10     -->     8
11     -->     11
12     -->     12
```

I'm looking for a formula that would calculate the new order position.

Comment: Do you even know what CSS you need to do write get the job done?

Comment: Can this be done without javascript or jquery?

Comment: CSS only. If no formula can be found I'll assign the order manually because this won't be dynamic and there will never be more than 30 elements.

Comment: The sequence is so messed up that you can't use pure CSS to rearrange them.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know how to apply this in your language so I will provide C++ example instead (just extract the formula). The second example is easy:

```
const int xs=3;                     // max numer of numbers in line
const int ys=9;                     // nuber of lines
AnsiString layout()
    {
    AnsiString txt;
    int i,x,y;
    for (i=1,x=0,y=0;y<ys;i++)
        {
        if (i<100) txt+=" ";        // align to 3 digits
        if (i< 10) txt+=" ";
        txt+=" "+AnsiString(i);     // add number to layout text
        if (y%(xs+1)==0) { x++; if (x>=xs) { x=0; y++; txt+="\r\n"; }}  // xs numbers per line
        else                                    { y++; txt+="\r\n"; }   // single number per line
        }
    return txt;
    }
```

This is the output:

```
   1   2   3
   4
   5
   6
   7   8   9
  10
  11
  12
  13  14  15
```

- `AnsiString` is just string class from **VCL**
- I output the result into string `txt` so just change it to your output type
- `"\r\r"` means end of line
- `x,y` is the actual position of item `i` so you can use it to position the cells
- `a%b` is remainder of `a/b`

The first example is not long enough to get the formula from it. Actual provided chunk is not regular. If you just have a bug in it and the algorithm is the same then just change the `xs` constant to `xs=2` In that case the output looks like:

```
   1   2
   3
   4
   5   6
   7
   8
   9  10
  11
  12
```